# Kernel pid terminated error in application_controller after upgrading and dockerizing Elixir/Phoenix application

Tags: docker, elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm upgrading an Elixir/Phoenix application from 1.7.4 to 1.11.4 and also dockerizing it. I've managed to update the dependencies and run it with `iex -S mix phx.server`. Also, I am able to generate a release locally and run it successfully as you can see below:

```
MIX_ENV=prod mix release jujuba

Compiling 2 files (.ex)
Compiling crate file_worker in release mode (native/file_worker)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 0.85s
* assembling jujuba-24.61.1 on MIX_ENV=prod
* using config/runtime.exs to configure the release at runtime

Release created at _build/prod/rel/jujuba!

    # To start your system
    _build/prod/rel/jujuba/bin/jujuba start

Once the release is running:

    # To connect to it remotely
    _build/prod/rel/jujuba/bin/jujuba remote

    # To stop it gracefully (you may also send SIGINT/SIGTERM)
    _build/prod/rel/jujuba/bin/jujuba stop

To list all commands:

    _build/prod/rel/jujuba/bin/jujuba
```

And when I run it with `_build/prod/rel/jujuba/bin/jujuba start` it starts normally. However, when I build an image of it and try to run it fails.

I'm building and running with docker with these commands:

```
docker build --progress=plain . -t jujuba:24.61.1
docker run -p 4000:4000 jujuba:24.61.1
```

And it gives this error:

```
docker run -p 4000:4000 jujuba:24.61.1
warning: :simple_one_for_one strategy is deprecated, please use DynamicSupervisor instead
  (elixir 1.11.4) lib/supervisor.ex:604: Supervisor.init/2
  (stdlib 3.17.2.2) supervisor.erl:330: :supervisor.init/1
  (stdlib 3.17.2.2) gen_server.erl:423: :gen_server.init_it/2
  (stdlib 3.17.2.2) gen_server.erl:390: :gen_server.init_it/6
  (stdlib 3.17.2.2) proc_lib.erl:226: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3

{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,jujuba,{bad_return,{{'Elixir.jujuba.Application',start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{undef,[{'Elixir.jujuba.Application',start,[normal,[]],[]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,\"application_master.erl\"},{line,293}]}]}}}}}"}
Kernel pid terminated (application_controller) ({application_start_failure,jujuba,{bad_return,{{'Elixir.jujuba.Application',start,[normal,[]]},{'EXIT',{undef,[{'Elixir.jujuba.Application',start,[normal,[]],[]},{application_master,start_it_old,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,293}]}]}}}}})
```

My Dockerfile looks like this

```bash
FROM hexpm/elixir:1.11.4-erlang-24.3.4.8-alpine-3.17.0 as build

RUN apk add --update git build-base
RUN apk add curl

RUN mkdir jujuba
WORKDIR jujuba

ENV MIX_ENV prod

RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- --quiet -y
RUN source "$HOME/.cargo/env"
RUN mix do local.hex --force, local.rebar --force

RUN mkdir ./apps
RUN mkdir ./apps/jujuba

COPY mix.* ./
COPY ./mix.* ./apps/jujuba/
COPY ./mix.* ./apps/jujuba/
RUN mix deps.get --only $MIX_ENV
RUN mix deps.compile

COPY config ./config

RUN mix phx.digest

COPY rel ./rel
RUN PORT=4000 MIX_ENV=prod mix release jujuba

FROM alpine:3.17 AS app
# install runtime dependencies
RUN apk add --update openssl postgresql-client

# copy release to app container
COPY --from=build ./jujuba/_build/prod/rel/jujuba/ .

CMD ["sh", "/bin/jujuba", "start"]
```

Do you have any hint on what I'm doing wrong?

Here is how my supervisor looks like:

```elixir
defmodule Jujuba.Application do
    use Application
  
    require Logger
  
    def start(_type, _args) do
      # Define workers and child supervisors to be supervised
      children = [
        # Telemetry
        JujubaWeb.Telemetry,
        # Start the endpoint when the application starts
        JujubaWeb.Endpoint,
  
        # Start the Ecto repository
        Jujuba.Repo.Master,
  
        # Start the flow builder supervisor
        {FlowBuilder.Supervisor, []},

        # Start AMQP Client
        {AMQPClient.Supervisor, []},
        # Start the generic contact import flow builder supervisor
        ContactImportFlowBuilder.Supervisor,

        # Start your own worker by calling: Jujuba.Worker.start_link(arg1, arg2, arg3)
  
        # Connection to Redis
        {Redix,
         name: :redix,
         host: Application.get_env(:redix, :host),
         port: Application.get_env(:redix, :port),
         password: Application.get_env(:redix, :password)},
  
        {Phoenix.PubSub, name: JujubaWeb.PubSub, adapter: Phoenix.PubSub.PG2}
      ]
  
      JujubaWeb.PlugPipelineInstrumenter.setup()
      JujubaWeb.MetricsExporter.setup()
      Jujuba.RepoInstrumenter.setup()
      JujubaWeb.PhoenixInstrumenter.setup()
  
      opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Jujuba.Supervisor]
  
      Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
    end
  end
```

Comment: Can you run the Elixir release on your host system, without Docker or `iex`?  What does your root supervisor look like?  It looks like you're copying the release into `/` in the container, which means the release's `./bin` directory overlaps the system `/bin`; is there a potential conflict here, and could you install the release somewhere else in the final image?

Comment: Yes, I can run it on host system without Docker with no problem. I have edited the question to show how my supervisor looks. Also, tried to change the copy command from root to /jujuba and it still does not work.